# Does Linux (CentOS) log when it dumps the memory cache?

Tags: linux, memory, centos6, cache

I have a python script that threw a MemoryError and I can see a giant change in cache (it was emptied) in a graph on an external monitoring system. Does CentOS dump memory cache when it reaches a certain threshold? Or maybe when it detects a failed process? If so, does this get logged anywhere? Or must I create a kind of cron/script to listen for this sort of thing?

Comment: #1 a python script that "threw a memory error".  Please elaborate on this.
#2 giant change in cache: which cache?  CPU cache?  L1/2/3 ?
#3 dump memory cache?  Do you mean CPU cache eviction/invalidation?  This will happen whenever there is a GPF and you exectute the general protection interrupt handler.  DMESG should present this to you as an "oops" trace.

Comment: Sounds like your script demanded a large amount of memory, causing the host OS to flush its read cache in order to make room for the memory demand. Everything but your script sounds normal here.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, an oops trace should be present in the DMESG log if the GP handler was executed.  Prior to this, the CPU will execute an "invalidate" to all CPU cache